# hoverColor disabled if child has color: flutter

Tags: flutter

I have this code snippet:

```
Card(
     child: InkWell(
              hoverColor: Colors.lightBlue.shade200,
              splashColor: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
              onTap: () {
                print("tapped");
              },
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                color: int.parse(map['days']).remainder(2) == 0 ? Colors.lightBlue.shade50 : Colors.lightBlue.shade100,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                height: 30.0,
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Text(
                    map['name'],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
    ),
)
```

the hoverColor, splashColor etc do not have any effect with the color of the container specified. Disabling the container color setting means I have to give up the alternating color scheme I need.

Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: what about using `Card`'s color instead of `Container`, can you  include more details about use cases, what type of ux you are trying to archive?

Comment: That worked, thanks. So, as I understand, the `InkWell` color is "below" that of the `Container` (which is transparent by default). By moving the color to the `Card` the `InkWell`'s color is now "above" that of the `Card` and so it is visible.